# Color customization in Google forms

Tags: google-forms

Google forms is automatically altering color when I insert a custom photo banner (which does not match our brand). How and where can I enter in a specific color code (if possible)? Is there a specific format that should be used? (HTML, RGB, CMYK?)

Also, the initial box IN the email seems to be defaulting to a red/burgundy color scheme. Is this normal, and is it also able to be changed?